# Data Recovery software doesn't recover recently deleted files but can recover year old files

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have deleted a `zip` archive from my `E:` drive which was really important to me about 3 days ago.
Since I really needed it back, I ended up using Data Recovery software like eraseus data recover. 
This software showing me a lot of files that I can recover, but almost all of them are really old (months old, or some of them are years old), and wouldn't even show a file that I have recently deleted even if i try a deep scan.
Can anyone please explain me why I cannot recover recently deleted file ?

Answer (score 3):

Data recovery is always a bit of a mixed bag. Files that are deleted aren't actually erased and are marked as "can be overwritten".

A file you deleted 3 days ago, you would expect to be easier to recover. However, depending on where on the drive it was saved, it may have already been written over. A file that was deleted months ago could be closer to the end of the drive, and not in imminent danger of being fully erased from the drive itself.

That said, it might be worth trying different recovery software, as the detection may vary between different packages, avoiding writing anything else to the drive until you've fully exhausted the options.

Comment: Files are also a great deal harder to recover if they are on an SSD, rather than HD.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, the longer a deleted file sits, the more likely it is to be overwritten or otherwise irretrievably lost. So the percentage chance an older files can be recovered is lower than for more recently-deleted files.

But that doesn't overcome the difference in prevalence.

Say you have 10 recently-deleted files and 5,000 files not recently deleted. Even if 20% of your recently-deleted files and only 2% of your older files are recoverable, that will still mean only about 2 recently-deleted files and about 100 files not recently deleted.

Answer (score -1):

To be said,data recovery can only recover the data that hasn't been overwritten by new files.Only in this situation,you data can be recover.Maybe your recently deleted files have been overwritten.